# Using colons in querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, selectors-api

I'm trying to use the `querySelectorAll()` method to grab links in web pages, but I want to ignore links that begin with "javascript:" or use another protocol like "itpc://"

Is there any way to include these in a "not()" pseudo selector?

```
document.querySelectorAll("a:not([href^=javascript]):not([href^=itpc])"); //works
document.querySelectorAll("a:not([href^=javascript:]):not([href^=itpc://])"); //doesn't work
```

Even though the first method works fine on the current page, there's no guarantee that it will work on every page I'll be using it on, so I'd really like to be able to detect that colon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings), turning the values you want to target into [strings](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings) will work:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a:not([href^='javascript:']):not([href^='itpc://'])");
```

The problem with your current version is that unless you use quotes the values have to conform to the restrictions placed on [identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), which they do not.